# Dynamic google-code-prettify doesn't work

Tags: javascript, google-code-prettify

Is it possible for a button to call a function that would 'prettify' a dynamic `<code><pre>`? I can't get it to work.

After the page loads, the initial `<code>` is prettified(?), but when I change it and call prettyPrint() afterwards, it no longer works.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/uwBjD/2/

Edit: Sorry, I was using a local prettify.js. Updated it, still encountered the same error.

Comment: Did you look at the console? It pretty explicitly tells you, `prettyPrint is not defined` for me. This may have to do with the fact that one of your scripts, [prettify.js](http://apps-02.rwmanila.com/Scripts/prettify.js), is 404ing.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Apparently after the code is prettified, an additional class is added which is `prettyprinted`.  Anything with the class of `prettyprinted` is not re-prettified.  You need to remove that class before recalling the function:

```
$('input[type=button]').click( function() {
    $("#jsExample").text("    var user = 'private'; //Do NOT store your API Key on a script.")
        .parent().removeClass("prettyprinted");

   prettyPrint();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uwBjD/3/

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/source/browse/trunk/js-modules/prettify.js#905

Comment: Excellent! I battled against this for an hour ;)

Comment: @James, Google has a tarded way of dealing with things.

Comment: Great! Worked for me!