# Show xml content in div

Tags: xml, html

I am getting json response from server through ajax call.
One parameter in json contain xml.
But when i set the content of that parameter to div it is not showing xml data.
How can i show the xml content in div and if possible formatted xml data.

Comment: Could you show your code how are you setting the XML to the div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Don't set the XML as the innerHTML. Create an inner text node, e.g.

  ```
  elem.appendChild( document.createTextNode(yourXmlString) );
  ```
- [Google Code Prettify](https://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/) could help

Comment: Now i am able to show xml in div and using [link]https://vkbeautify.googlecode.com/files/vkbeautify.0.99.00.beta.js i can properly indent xml. Google prettify is also very good but its only style content while page loading. I wasn't able to find how to prettify javascript function on button click.

Comment: @dmay Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15983894/dynamic-google-code-prettify-doesnt-work