# Google prettify,prettyPrint() doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-code-prettify

Today I downloads prettify-4-Mar-2013.tar.bz2.And I use the "prettify.css" and "prettify.js" in it. I know I can use it in an easy way just use the "run_prettify.js", but I want to serve my own JS & CSS. Here's my html.

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="prettify.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src='prettify.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        prettyPrint();
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <pre class="prettyprint">
        class Voila {
            public:
                // Voila
                static const string VOILA = "Voila";

                // will not interfere with embedded
        }
    </pre>
</body>
```

Here's my javascript. (I have imported jQuery.js,prettify.css,prettify.js.) All of the javascripts following do not work.

```
$(function() {
    prettyPrint();
});
```

Or

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    prettyPrint();
});
```

The error message is "Uncaught TypeError: Property 'prettyPrint' of object [object Object] is not a function "

Or

```
<body onload="prettyPrint()">
```

still do not work.

Comment: see console is the javascript path is correct

Comment: What does `console.log(typeof prettyPrint)` produce?

Comment: "undefined",I'm really confused! I promise all the js are imported!

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/a/15984048/632951