# Chrome Developer Tools / debugger: "pretty print" does not work

Tags: google-chrome, developer-tools

The "pretty print" button, located in the lower left corner of the Chrome Developer Tools window, is supposed to make minified code readable. However, when I click it, nothing happens. I tried both single and double-clicks. This happes on Chrome 32 on Windows.

How do I make the pretty-print button work?

Comment: Here is your answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/15984048/632951

Answer (score 7):

I just stumbled upon this problem and, while `Pretty-print` doesn't do anything for me, I make it work by clicking the curly braces icon `{}` in the left bottom corner on the status bar. This suggestion came from `Learn more` button next to `Pretty-print`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As I found out the hard way (by trial and error) the "pretty print" button is only functional when the console is visible. That means it does not work here:

[image]

But it does work here (console visible):

[image]

Comment: How can you tell? If you're looking at the console window, how can you see whether the source code is formatted?

Comment: Obviously I resized the window prior to taking the screenshot. In order to make that crystal-clear I replaced the second screenshot with a new one.

Comment: Doesn't make any difference for me -- it doesn't work in either case.

Comment: Still no dice for me when I try to prettify [this javascript](http://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/custom/africa.js).  [Here's a screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/nGDxCa3.png)

Comment: not working for me either. the button opens a new tab with the same non-prettified code.

Comment: it doesn't work for me either, but I have included a large library in my javascript file and I think that might be the reason.

Comment: I switched to firefox for now, which can beatify my script just fine.

Comment: My issue was that I had commented out a comment in my code, so it couldn't format it. It worked once I fixed that. Make sure you don't have any syntax errors in your code.