# Javascript prettyPrint an external java file

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-code-prettify

I'm really new to web development and I'm kind of lost here.

I'm using Bootstrap, and I'm trying to display java code (in a file called test.java) that's on my local machine on the webpage. The file is displayed, but it doesn't get syntax coloured. Please help!

I have in the header:

for prettify:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../localfile/prettify.css"/>
<script src="https://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/loader/run_prettify.js"></script>
<script src="../localfile/prettify.js"></script>
```

and for jQuery:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

And this is the script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
     jQuery(function($) {
         $.get('test.java', function(data) {
             $('#sourceCodeDestination').html(data);
             prettyPrint();
         }, "text");
     });
 });
</script>
```

and this for the div:

```
<div class="panel-body" >
       <pre id="sourceCodeDestination" class="prettyprint linenums lang-java">
        </pre>
</div>
```

Comment: `$.get` wont work on the local file system, you need a web server setup

Comment: I looked around and found that it could work on Firefox. It does display the file content, but the problem is that it's not syntax coloured.

Comment: not an answer but `$(document).ready(function() ` and `jQuery(function ($) {` pretty much mean the same thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out what the problem was after reading the answer to this question, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15983894/dynamic-google-code-prettify-doesnt-work).

So, I changed the script to this and it works just fine. I just removed the prettyprinted class before calling prettyPrint.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

      jQuery(function ($) {  $.get('test.java', function(data) {
      $('#sourceCodeDestination').html(data);
      $('#sourceCodeDestination').removeClass("prettyprinted");
        prettyPrint();  
    }, "text");
 });

</script>
```